# Cannot kill children on trap

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, kill, background-process

I am stuck with something unexpected to me:

I am trying to make a chat script and set to call function on '`Ctrl`+`Z`'

```
trap 'chat_unloop' 20
```

But in the code I have some rows that starts child background subprocesses

```
while cat $P1 | sed -rn "s/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\:/\1[$(date +%H:%M:%S)]> /p" ; do : Nothing; done &
```

And pressing `Ctrl`+`Z` causes this:

```
^Z[1]+ Stopped   bash script.sh
```

And process disconnect terminal but whole process is on (with all child subprocesses)

**What was tried:**

```
trap 'pkill -P $$; chat_unloop' 20 
trap 'kill -9 $(pgrep -P $$); chat_unloop' 20
trap 'chat_unloop' SIGTSTP
trap 'chat_unloop' TSTP
```

**Looking for:**
Something that can close all child processes and call function without shell disconnect

**Edit 1:**
`P1` is file with fifo named pipe

**Edit 2:**

```
chat_unloop(){
    CHAT_LOCK=0
    trap - 20
    clear
    options=()
}
P1='/path/to/pipe.fifo'
[[ -p "$P1" ]] || mkfifo --mode=777 $P1
while cat $P1 | sed -rn "s/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\:/\1[$(date +%H:%M:%S)]> /p" ; do : Nothing; done &
trap 'chat_unloop' 20
while [[ $CHAT_LOCK -eq 1 ]] && read text
do
    echo "$text" >> $P1
done
clear
```

**Edit 3:**

```
79394 script.sh #actual script process
  >79414 script.sh #pipe 2
  >79405 script.sh #pipe 1 (with $! I receive this)
     >82368 script.sh #while loop for pipe 1
```

Comment: Why do you trap `SIGWINCH`?

Comment: @schily `SIGWINCH` has code 28, and `CTRL`+`Z`, which is `SIGTSTP`, has code 20

Comment: `SIGWINCH` has number 20 since 1982. `SIGTSTP` has number 24. You may however not be on UNIX and guess why it is not recommended to use numbers...

Comment: @schily I am on Fedora... does that makes any difference?

Comment: Linux is not UNIX... Why don't you use TSTP as `trap` argument if you like to trap `SIGTSTP`?

Comment: @schily And i know that code 20 is working because without subprocessing `Ctrl+Z` works perfectly

Comment: @schily Well,... maybe because it's has same results?(tried few seconds ago)

Comment: if your script has open files you could get pids with lsof -t and send kill -2

Comment: @alecxs kill -2 closed only one of the actual pipes (in real code i have for loop which opens many fifo pipes)

Comment: You should explain which commands you like to kill. `pgrep -P <pid>` only lists pids for direct children of the shell. The while loop seems to run in the background and may not be such a direct child.

Comment: @alecxs I can't send full code because `writing all this frome mobile phone`

Comment: @schily ok, so... about that... i posted edit 3 on how process looks like.

Comment: doesn't `lsof -t $P1` print all pids to be killed? (of course you need a loop for kill -2)

Comment: @alecxs well it is... but with kill -2 it didnt killed all subprocesses... and many of those files pid connected to xfce...

Comment: maybe your while cat loop respawns too fast (for lsof method)

Comment: @alecxs so there is no way to do that...?... or it's posible but not easy?

Comment: @alecxs And, no `lsof -t $P1` returns nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. so i solved that:

1. I changed `trap` to trap `ctrl` + `c`, by setting

```
trap 'chat_unloop' 2
```

2. I moved trap closer to function witch he needs to execute, so i have:

```
chat_unloop(){
...
trap - 2
...
}
trap 'chat_unloop' 2
...
```

And that somehow worked...
maybe it's because `trap` only traps for current process, but sends same signal to subprocesses

So thank you for everyone who tried to help me